# Bad formatted json

Tags: ruby-on-rails, json, ruby-on-rails-4

There is a model Event in my app and I have two problems, the first is the returned json that comes messed with the request:

```
$ curl http://0.0.0.0:3000/events
```

it gives me

```
{
  "events":[
            {"events":{"name":"First"}},
            {"events":{"name":"Second"}}],
            "meta":{"total_pages":9,
                    "next_page":"http://0.0.0.0:3000/events?page=2"}
}
```

which I think it should gives

```
{
      "events":[
                  {"name":"First" },
                  {"name":"Second"}
               ],
               "meta":{
                       "total_pages":9,
                       "next_page":"http://0.0.0.0:3000/events?page=2"
                      }
 }
```

also I am using the gems draper and active_model_serializer, and the second problem is that the json format doesn't respect the Serializer definition:

```
class EventSerializer < ActiveModel::Serializer
   attributes :id, :date_end
 end
```

I would like to know where should I look to fix these problems.

**Answering the questions, the code that generate the json:**

```
class EventsController < ApplicationController

def index
    @events = Event.order(:name).page(params[:page])      
    @events = @events.where(id: params[:ids].split(',')) if params[:ids].present?

    render json: @events.decorate, meta: { total_pages: @events.total_pages, next_page: next_page_url(@events)}

end

def next_page_url(event)
   unless event.last_page?
      next_page = event.current_page + 1 unless event.last_page?

      events_url(params.merge({:page => next_page}))
   end
end
```

and the decorator:

```
class EventDecorator < Draper::Decorator
delegate :current_page, :total_pages, :limit_value


  def name
    object.name
  end

 end
```

Comment: and your code that generates the json is where?

Comment: ^ second that. That is most likely where the error in your problem is.

Comment: I just added more code to the question to show where the json is generated.